# Como hacer un Json con php personalizado FEL

Tags: javascript, php, json, php5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hago para crear un JSON con varias llaves como este codigo en php es decir este json tiene 3 niveles de llaves `{{{ }}}`.

He buscado pero solo encuentro como generar 2 niveles y luego `[]` aparece esto

--EL JSON EMPIEZA EN EN EL

```
{"dte",
```

Aquí empieza el Json

```
{
    "dte": 
    {
        "datosGenerales":
        {
            "tipo": "FACT",
            "fechaHoraEmision": "2022-10-22T17:56:49",
            "codigoMoneda": "GTQ"
        },
    
        "emisor": 
        {
            "direccion": 
            {
                "direccion": "Guatemala",
                "codigoPostal": 0,
                "municipio": "Quetzaltenango",
                "departamento": "Quetzaltenango",
                "pais": "GT"
            },
            "nitEmisor": "17436664512321",
            "nombreEmisor": "Byron",
            "codigoEstablecimiento": 1,
            "nombreComercial": "Zapateria cifuentes",
            "correoEmisor": "prueba@gmail.com",
            "afiliacionIVA": "GEN"
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿A partir de dónde quieres construir el JSON, con qué código y con qué datos? Puedes poner los niveles de anidación que sean precisos, cuidando de construir una estructura válida. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta agregando el código que estás usando y los eventuales errores que tengas.

Comment: LO QUIERO CREAR DE CERO PERO QUE QUEDE EN LA ESTRUCTURA DE ARRIBA

Comment: ¿ *De cero* quiere decir tomar esa cadena a mano y crear un JSON ? ¿Qué código estás implementando para eso y hacia dónde quieres mandar ese JSON? ¿Qué código usas en el destino para consumirlo?

Answer (score 0):

puede usar los array para forma un Json personalizado, pero la estructura del json es un poco completa para acceder los datos

```
 $capitales = [
      array(
        'dte' => array(
          'datosGenerales' => array(
            'tipo' => 'FACT',
            'fechaHoraEmision' => '2022-10-22T17:56:49',
            'codigoMoneda' => 'GTQ',
            'emisor' => array(
              'direccion' => array(
                'direccion' => 'Guatemala'
              ),
            ),
          ),
          'emisor' => array(
            'direccion' => array(
              'direccion' => 'Guatemala',
              'codigoPostal' => 'estado'
            ),
            'nitEmisor' => '17436664512321',
            'nombreEmisor' => 'Byron',
            'codigoEstablecimiento' => 1,
          ),
        ),

      ),
    ];
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    return json_encode($capitales);
```